# i'm not able to change the status of the checkbox

Tags: electron

```
{
  label: 'Live preview',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: false,
  click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    menuItem.checked = true ? false : true;
    browserWindow.webContents.send('live-preview', menuItem.checked);        
  }
},
```

when i click on context menu on the menuItem **live preview** (checkbox) : **always unchecked**

**How to toggle checkbox when i click on the menuItem**

[image: 1]

[image]

**Solution:**

```
// initialise isChecked variable before the initialisation of context menu
var isChecked = false;

{
  label: 'Live preview',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: isChecked,
  click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    browserWindow.webContents.send('live-preview', menuItem.checked);
    isChecked = !isChecked;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please, add more details.

Comment: i know but you could see, in the image you can't make it checked, when click on the menuItem (live preview) , nothing change , always unchecked ... i will add an image to explain more what i need ...

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not set the boolean value of the checked attribute correctly.

Try:

```
menuItem.checked = !menuItem.checked
```

instead of:

```
menuItem.checked = true ? false : true;
```

#### Explanation:

The assignment `menuItem.checked = true ? false : true;` will always assign `false` to `menuItem.checked` since `true` is always... `true`.

If you want to flip the boolean using a ternary operator you would have to do

```
menuItem.checked = menuItem.checked ? false : true;
```

## Edit

Also, I think you need to actually set the `checked`-property correctly.

```
{
  label: 'Live preview',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: false,
  click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    menuItem.checked = !menuItem.checked;
    browserWindow.webContents.send('live-preview', menuItem.checked);        
  }
},
```

will result in your Checkbox always being unchecked, because of `checked: false`.

**Try out below code:**

```
{
  label: 'Live preview',
  type: 'checkbox',
  click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    menuItem.checked = !menuItem.checked; // toggles the menu item
    browserWindow.webContents.send('live-preview', menuItem.checked);        
  }
},
```